# Trying to make an Exit Button

Tags: vb.net, button

I have some code that I'm not sure about, I thought it worked on an old project but not sure where I've messed it up at.

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", MessageBox.Show(vbYesNo)) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then e.Cancel = True
End Sub
```

This is my giant error:

```
Error   1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Show' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
    'Public Shared Function Show(owner As System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window, text As String) As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult': Argument matching parameter 'owner' narrows from 'String' to 'System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window'.
    'Public Shared Function Show(owner As System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window, text As String) As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult': Argument matching parameter 'text' narrows from 'System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult' to 'String'.
    'Public Shared Function Show(text As String, caption As String) As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult': Argument matching parameter 'caption' narrows from 'System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult' to 'String'
```

Comment: Is this [vb.net] or [vba]?

Comment: It is just a simple calculator I'm attempting to make in vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why is there `MessageBox.Show(vbYesNo)` inside instead of just `vbYesNo`?

edit:
to be less snide: there is no overload of `Show` which takes a string and a DialogResult as parameters, nor one which takes a single MsgBoxStyle argument.
there is also no overload which takes a string and an MsgBoxStyle constant.
you probably mean

```
MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbYesNo)
```

or

```
MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
```

Comment: my attempt at getting it to work, I've tried it without and Ill keep trying but it was just last attempt at something I thought I've seen before.